# How to edit the imageField label text "Currently, ... ect"

Tags: python, django, django-forms

[image]
here i have a form i did find were to control label and input field of the imagefield but label only controls the Avatar text not the "currently ....ect",

is there a way to access it i want to add a class to style it and cant find its object in python ?

this my attempt and it is not working only gives me the "avatar" ext only

```
class ProfileUpdateModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'bio', 'avatar')

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['avatar'].label = False #hides "avatar" text and the rest of text still there
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are defined in [`ClearableFileInput`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9e872b59329393f615c440c54f632a49ab05b78/django/forms/widgets.py#L402):

```
class ClearableFileInput(FileInput):
    clear_checkbox_label = _('Clear')
    initial_text = _('Currently')
    input_text = _('Change')
    # ....
```

So you would have to subclass this widget, override the class attributes, and use it in the form field. Alternatively, you can override the template [`forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html) for total control over the display of the generated markup of the field.

Comment: how to override this template ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/ ;)

Comment: And even: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/renderers/#overriding-built-in-widget-templates